# «Неподконтрольный» — слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, прилагательные

*Сумма и срок выплаты варьируются в зависимости от наступления события, не подконтрольного покупателю или организации.*
Слитно или раздельно в данном предложении "неподконтрольного"?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что правильно писать слитно.
*Сумма и срок выплаты варьируются в зависимости от наступления события, **неподконтрольного** покупателю или организации.*

[Неподконтрольный](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/117541/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) (прил.) — неподвластный контролю со стороны кого-либо, чего-либо.

Слитно пишется **не** с прилагательными, которые не лишаются при этом утвердительного смысла, а лишь приобретают противоположное значение. Такие прилагательные имеют синонимы без **не**: свободный, стихийный, самостоятельный.

Из [учебника для вузов](https://books.google.ee/books?id=LYQ_DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA489&lpg=PA489&dq=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8.&source=bl&ots=FB1KeHAhO_&sig=ACfU3U1vh2I-bSqB9PjtXPoGf-gdxHh85Q&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiR2IjBvZHwAhUVHHcKHYnND7sQ6AEwCXoECAQQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8.&f=false):

> Другое дело, что риск может быть связан с неумелыми действиями предпринимателя, с его неумением правильно оценить и спрогнозировать рыночную ситуацию, но он может быть также обусловлен и факторами, **неподконтрольными** данному предпринимателю.

Из Нацкорпуса:
Он знал, что некий процент **неподконтрольного** ему распределения обязательно должен быть, нельзя все забирать себе ― это было следствие все того же главного жизненного принципа. [Андрей Белозеров. Чайка (2001)]
А если и обращаясь, то лишь в связи с давним беспокойством насчет возможности создания машинного, уже **неподконтрольного** нам интеллекта. [Дмитрий Биленкин. Тень совершенства // «Знание ― сила», 1982]

[НЕ с именами прилагательными](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=4.53#:%7E:text=%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D1%81%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8,%D0%B0%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5.)

Answer (score 0):

Слитно. Раздельно обычно пишут, когда есть противопоставление: "Не подконтрольного, а такого-то". А здесь просто свойство: он какой? — неподконтрольный.